# How to regenerate markers as clusters in android app on location change?

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing, markers

Hi there i have stuck in a problem in my app development. First i will tell you my scenario. I'm using google maps v2. It is displaying my location as a dragable marker. And various other markers are displayed as cluster. What i want is that on marker drag end event i want my current location to be updated and the corresponding nearby markers to be updated on the map. NOTE:- Im not using places API. instead i'm fetching location co-ordinates from the API which is stored in a local file in android.